# What kind of data structure should I use?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I've got a mysql table that has entries with a unique ID, then 3 properties.

I'm displaying the IDs in a ListBox, and the other information goes on other parts of my page.  It gets re-used often enough that I don't want to do another query every time I need to reference it. My question is this: What kind of data structure should I use to hold the row data?

Is a 2-dimensional array the best option?  If so, is it poor style to use a Hashtable with the key being the ID and the value being a reference to an array containing all the values for that row?

I'm using .NET 4, and coding this in C#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A model looks appropriate to represent a row:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

and `IEnumerable<Foo>` to represent your SQL table. You would then of course have a repository with methods allowing you to fetch a single model given it's `Id` or other criteria and to fetch all models. Then bind this model to your GUI.

Comment: I neglected to mention I wasn't sure if it was big enough to merit its own class - that seems like an excessive amount of overhead if I have to create potentially hundreds of these objects.

Comment: @uscere90, a model is also worth. **ALWAYS**. Far better than using `Hashtable`. A `Hashtable` is not strongly typed meaning that all your errors you will get at runtime instead of compile-time, not to mention the readability of your code and the poor souls that are going to maintain it. Always, always, always use strong typing. Let Hashtables, DataSets and companies die as quickly as possible.

Comment: What makes you think "its own class" represents an "excessive amount of overhead"?

Comment: @uscere90 - If you end up with hundreds fo types of objects, consider some type of O/R mapper to help you create the objects. You should not pound yourself silly over the plumbing. Having Domain Objects (good) does not necessarily equal "maintenance nightmare"

Comment: @Darin Ok, thanks. Not a veteran c# user, so I'm still feeling my way around some of these usage questions.  I'm a little confused as to how I'd use IEnumerable to make a collection of these Foo objects - that would be another class, right? Or can I just create a List<Foo>, since List<T> implements IEnumerable?

Comment: @uscere90, yeah, sure, `List<Foo>` already implements `IEnumerable<Foo>` so if you have a list you have an enumerable.

Comment: @Gregory @uscere90 agreed; there are tools for that, ranging from "just get me the data" (dapper-dot-net, petapoco) to full blown ORMs (EF, NHibernate, llblgenpro)

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to create a business object class out of it and pass it around as a List.

You can also use the built-in DataTable class if you just need raw data in a small app.

Comment: It is subjective, but *personally* I don't consider `DataTable` a very good mechanism for data. I just don't.

Comment: @Marc I personally agree with you, but I have lots of opinions that may not be valid for him. DataTable is reasonably generic so I figured it would work.

Comment: I've used it for binding data to a GridView, but not for storing data from a database.

Comment: the only place when a DataTable makes any sense is when you have to maintain some crappy/legacy code that you have no choice to modify. When writing new code this should never even be considered as something that exists.

Comment: Yup, and having a business object is obviously less error-prone because you access the same data in the same manner every time. My phrasing is poor, which I will correct, but DataTable nonetheless remains an option.

Answer (score 0):

I would store them in a DataSet which will contain a DataTable. Multiple datatables are returned and stored in one dataset if the situation arises. More here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978448.aspx#bdadotnetdata4_topic2c

Comment: It is subjective, but *personally* I don't consider `DataTable` a very good mechanism for data. I just don't.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, no, it's not subjective. It's simply true :-)

Comment: @Marc: He's pulling it from a database and displaying it in a ListBox/ListView. You can easily bind a Listbox/ListView to a DataTable. The DataTable is a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

I am not fond of the way you have the Hashtable set up, as an array of values is potentially a bit sloppy. I would aim more for Hashtable, if you want to bind in that manner. Tehcnically, however, you don't have to go to this level, as you can set up any object type that can use IEnumerable and bind. Example:

```
List<ObjectType> myList = new List<ObjectType>();
```

As you are binding to one property on the object and then displaying, according to a filter (LINQ to Entities?), you have the ability to reuse the data based on the user's filter.

One possible warning is watch the size of the data you are holding on the web server side, especially if this loaded on a "per session" type of basis, as you can end up consuming large amounts of memory to handle all possible user selections. Ouch!